# playing video in ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I wanted to play a video in ios 6. I am using Xcode 4.5. I write code below but getting error

```
 Test Demo[736:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
 Test Demo[736:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
 Test Demo[736:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
```

and my code

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestVideo" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: streamURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099393/cannot-play-video-with-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many issues for your error.

1) Set a property for your `MPMoviePlayerController` and synthesize it. This may occur, if your MPMoviePlayerController releases before it plays.

2) add this code `player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;`

3) As per [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `.m4v` extension is not mentioned to play.

4)  Below screenshot will help you about supported formats.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *url   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"santaMessage" ofType:@"mp4"];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;

moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;

[moviePlayer play];
```

///this worked like a charm

Comment: should work but i am doing debug and url is nil
what i am doing wrong.  NSBundler it's not working