# iOS 7 video not being played

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

i have used MPMoviePlayerController to play a video but this only shows the black screen. not played my video. this code is correct. where may i wrong....

i have done this code to play video..

```
    NSString * str=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"iGreet" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL * url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
    MPMoviePlayerController * movieController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    movieController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [movieController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
    [movieController prepareToPlay];
    [movieController play];
```

Any help appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you hearing any sound?

Comment: why dont u just present the movieController and then play

Comment: i feel like we get questions like this atleast daily on SO...

Comment: not get sound.. only black screen apperars..

Comment: check this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133023/playing-video-in-ios-6?rq=1

Comment: According to the documentation, the MPMoviePlayerController class plays any movie or audio file with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to play video from resource then you need mentioned this:

```
   [movieController setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
```

Comment: Legend! I was pulling my hair out, not many examples include this tidbit!

Answer (score 1):

This is my code. I have a button that show image an image for my video.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer;
```

add this to your .h file.

> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
>                     @"http://www.mydomain/video/1.mp4"];

```
_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];
CGRect frame = _btnVideo.frame;
[_moviePlayer.view setFrame:frame];
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), .m4v extension is not mentioned to play.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and it works fine:

```
NSString *videoFileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoName ofType:@"m4v" inDirectory:nil];

self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFileName]];
[self.moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.infoViewController.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```